# Vim history deleted by git reset --hard

Tags: git, vim, undo

I'm using vim 7.3 with

```
:verbose set history
```

set to 10000,

but my whole history on a file dissapears when doing git reset --hard or similar operations with git that removes or clears files not added or checked in to git.

Why is that? My normal history is saved in my ~ folder with the following setting in my .vimrc:

```
set backupdir=~/.vimswp
set swapfile
set dir=~/.vimswp
set undodir=~/.vimswp
```

Comment: This is best suited for super user.

Comment: does your vim history file appear in `git status` after you did some commands to fill it in? If so, you might want to play with your `.gitignore` or rethink the directory structure.

Comment: Are you talking about the undo history or the command line history.

Answer (score 0):

> does your vim history file appear in git status after you did some commands to fill it in? If so, you might want to play with your .gitignore or rethink the directory structure. –  Mykola Gurov 20 hours ago

No, any vim history is not managed by git. my .gitignore includes:
*.swp
*.un~

> Are you talking about the undo history or the command line history. –  FDinoff 33 mins ago
>   The undo history.